# How to know the extension when decrypting files that do not know the original extension

Tags: c, encryption, aes

Hi I am wondering what to do when decrypting an encrypted file that does not know the original extension while studying aes ctr encryption from this link at https://www.gurutechnologies.net/blog/aes-ctr-encryption-in-c/ To
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Wrap the file in a data structure that preserves its original filename, exertion, date created/modified dates, etc., and then encrypt that entire structure

Answer (score 0):

The "classic" UNIX way (as done by compress, gzip, bzip2, xz, ...) is to keep the original file name and append (not replace) your own extension, so if you encrypt the file `foo.txt`, you'll output - say - a `foo.txt.enc` file. When decrypting, just remove the `.enc` extension.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Linux [`file`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/file) command to see what a file may contain and append the extension manually.

If you're running windows, a quick google search showed that [TrID](http://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html) has similar functionality.

Comment: There are a lot of file types that have ambiguous extension (doc and dot files are identical), can legitimately have extensions variants (.jpg, .jpeg), are effectively archives with a changed extension (.docx, .odt and .jar, for example, are all zip files), are indeed of multiple types (xhtml files are legitimate xml files - who knows how the original was named?), or can be multiple file types combined (many auto-extracting executables are both zip and exe at the same time, thanks to the zip header being at the end of an archive). And what about custom file formats `file` knows nothing about?

Comment: More in general, the extension has a certain degree of arbitrariety, and in line of principle it may not even be related with the content at all. Trying to guess it with heuristics (as `file` does) it's not the way to go. Just keep it somewhere in the cyphered stream (or in the cyphered file name).

Comment: @MatteoItalia it is arbitrary indeed, and ambiguous as well. My fault was understanding the question more like "what is this data I decrypted?". But adding metadata (such as the filename, or the extra information Alexander suggested in his comment) makes the encryption/decryption process dependant on the tool used to encrypt/decrypt, which I don't think it's a good idea either.